# how to open terminal with firefox?

Tags: firefox, permissions, terminal, sh, execute

I have an executable file with .sh extension. I want to open this file through firefox with Terminal but it return an error:

> "filename.sh" can't be opened because Firefox is not allowed to open documents in Terminal.

now, how can I change the permissions to resolve this out?

Answer (score 1):

A more secure method working in all modern browsers with javascript can be found here:

1. Install the websocketd server (single static linked binary)
   download from http://websocketd.com/
2. Start the websocketd server:

   ./websocketd --port=8080 --devconsole ./command.sh
3. Write an HTML page and a small bash script

**HTML:**

```
     <button type = "button"
                  onclick = ws.send("xterm\040#started")>xterm </button>
```

**Javascript**
open a websocket:

```
          var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/');
```

**Bash script(command.sh):**

```
        #!/bin/bash
        export DISPLAY=:0.0
        while read command
          do
            eval $command
          done
```

more details:
http://www.bitkistl.com/2016/01/websockets-with-interactive-bash-script.html

Answer (score 0):

It is normally disabled because it can allow malware to damage your files. For instance this STIG Viewer topic [Network shell protocol is enabled in FireFox.](http://www.stigviewer.com/stig/mozilla_firefox/2014-03-21/finding/V-15771)

However, it is configurable, called the "Shell Protocol".  The blog entry *[Firefox: Enable starting of scripts and applications from an HTML page](http://bitkistl.blogspot.com/2015/04/firefox-enable-starting-of-scripts-and.html)* goes into some detail, showing settings for

- network.protocol-handler.external.shell (true)
- network.protocol-handler.app.install (a custom shell)
- network.protocol-handler.app.shell (a custom shell)